# How to get the list of all files in android device^s internal memory?

Tags: java, android, delete-file, java-io

I know there are lots of same or similar topics not only in stackoverflow but also in other sources in internet world. None of them helped me so I needed to ask my particular case. In fact, at the beginning I was thinking that it was not a particular necessity as other developers must need it in a way while programing in the android world, but now reliased that it is not. It became a big challange for me indeed. :)

I can create, write, read, check of existance of a file by using File object without a problem. A sample copy of them in my code as folllows which is working perfectly.

```
public static boolean fileExist(Context mContext, String fileName){
    File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir() + fileName);
    return file.exist;
}
```

The story started after that. I am creating many files with txt entension while my app running. These are temporary files. So I decided to add a method which will be invoked at the first line in main_activity in order the clean all txt files for a fresh start. (by the way, I am using Android Studio with Java).

I have written a method as follows:

```
public static void deleteWithExtension(Context mContext,String extension){
    File dir = new File(mContext.getFilesDir() + extension);
        final String[] theFiles = dir.list();
        for (final String file : theFiles) {
            //do something here....
            //The code never goes to here, because theFiles Array is always null
        }
    }
```

As you may guess, it is not working. My inspections with Android studio's debug option, say that TheFiles[] array is null. So the code never goes inside the for loop.

I have seen many similar questions in internet sources. Some of them was about device external memory or was about using different ways, but none of them worked.

I would be very appreciated if you can give me a code to achive my purpose. Thank you in advance. I am familiar with other languages on PC side and I am very suprised that such simple process caused me  big headache....

Comment: `mContext.getFilesDir() + extension` is not a directory. Use `mContext.getFilesDir()` to list all the files. In your `for` loop, for any file that ends with your desired extension, take some action.

Comment: This Q must be a duplicate of so many

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually, I had tried what you said. I am getting red-underlined error when I remove that part.  It does not accept "mContext.getFilesDir() alone. I should add something more to that. I tried * (asterisk) or / (slash) or /* (slashasterisk)  or many other options but no chance...